# 'quoted to you' or 'quoted for you'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

Which is correct?

> The price we quoted **for** you

or

> The price we quoted **to** you

I often stumble with this. I'm not sure how to use *for you* and *to you*.

Comment: 'Quote' in this sense is ditransitive: it doesn't need a preposition. 'The price we quoted you' works fine and sounds most natural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I think they mean roughly the same thing, I do see one difference between those two.

As Edwin suggests in the comment above, *The price we quoted to you* is exactly identical in meaning to *The price we quoted you*

Maybe I disagree with Edwin (or maybe not), but I see a small potential difference in the *for you* construction. *The price we quoted for you* means *The price we quoted **for your sake***.

With ditransitive verbs, we usually think of the preposition-less form as implying one particular relation between that object and the verb. For quote, we assume "to". If you say *for you*, then you mean

Thus, to give a similar example:

> The poem I wrote for you

= the poem was something I wrote on your behalf

versus

> The poem I wrote to you

= The poem I wrote to give to you

The sentence *the poem I wrote you* is identical in meaning with the latter.

To give a dissimilar example, *the cake I baked you* is identical to *the cake I baked for you* and *the cake I baked to you* is ungrammatical.

Comment: I'm niot disagreeing, but isn't that usually (i.e. identical to)  *The ice cream I bought you*?

Comment: I think it is in the case of *bought*. But the ice cream I bought to you is non-grammatical. Maybe it's just AmE but I assume the second object to be "to you" with quote and would not infer "for you" in that case.

Comment: @TimLymington okay, I've switched out the example and incorporated the knowledge I gained from your comment

Comment: I'm not disagreeing either. A good analysis. But being me, I'll add an ambiguous case: 'He wrote me a letter'. Usually means 'to' but can mean 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

'For' and 'To' have many different uses in different situation.

In your case above this would be the correct answer in my opinion:

> The price we quoted to you.

Comment: How about an explanation of why?  Perhaps expand upon those many different uses.